# Append a IDictionary<string,string> to a WebHeaderCollection

Tags: c#, linq

How can I append a `IDictionary<string,string>` to a `System.Net.WebHeaderCollection`?

Or even append 2 `System.Net.WebHeaderCollection` objects? I am attempting to add many custom headers to my `HttpWebRequest`and overwrite the key value pairs in the source Dictionary named `request.Headers`.

My current code gets a casting problem:

> Error 1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'

```
// IDictionary <string, string> customHeaders; // populated earlier in the code
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

// Compiler error below
request.Headers.Concat(customHeaders).GroupBy(d => d.Key)
                    .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.First().Value);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
foreach(var customHeader in customHeaders)
    request.Headers.Add(customHeader.Key, customHeader.Value);
```

`Concat` is not an in-place operation, it only returns the concatenated collections. So even if it *did* compile, it wouldn't actually work.

In any case, to iterate over the headers using a generic IEnumerable, you would need to do this:

`request.Headers.Cast<HttpRequestHeader>()`

And this should make it clear why you can't concat a ***Dictionary*** with ***IEnumerable<.HttpRequestHeader>***